# Operation Warning about SDK Version Issue (xcode 10.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

upload my xcode to 10.1 when i get the warning

> WARNING ITMS-90725:
>    "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. Starting March 2019

and set up deployment target as follows
`build setting → General →　Development Target「12.1」`

but i still get such as the following when i distribute my App

> App Store Connect Operation Warning
>   WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later."
>
> App Store Connect Operation Warning
>   WARNING ITMS-90747: "Architecture incompatible with MinimumOSVersion. The app bundle at '[Aplication Name].app' specifies a MinimumOSVersion of '12.1' but contains a 32-bit architecture that is unsupported on iOS 12 and later."
>
> App Store Connect Operation Warning
>   WARNING ITMS-90747: "Architecture incompatible with MinimumOSVersion. The app bundle at '[Aplication Name].app/PlugIns/[Aplication Name] StickerPackExtension.appex' specifies a MinimumOSVersion of '12.1' but contains a 32-bit architecture that is unsupported on iOS 12 and later."

Do i need worry about the warning thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you are setting deployment target it means that the app will be installed on the device which has the at least the deployment target version.

For eg.

As you set `General →　Development Target → 12.1`. The app will not be installed on the devices runs lower iOS version than 12.1

**Point 1**

> WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. Starting March 2019

This warning is nothing to worry about, if you succeed to submit your app to App Store. it is just a reminder from Apple.

**Point 2**

> App Store Connect Operation Warning WARNING ITMS-90747: "Architecture incompatible with MinimumOSVersion. The app bundle at '[Aplication Name].app' specifies a MinimumOSVersion of '12.1' but contains a 32-bit architecture that is unsupported on iOS 12 and later."

You also need to make from 32-bit architecture to 64-bit architecture bcoz 2-bit architecture that is unsupported on iOS 12 and later

Comment: Mr @Mahendra Thank you very much for replying.I am so relieved to hear that.

Comment: So how do we do this?

Comment: Um, From my experience I cannot upload to the App Store with this error.  Thus it is definitely something about which to worry.

Comment: If you try to upload build on App Store with latest Xcode, you will not see this warning.